# retrieve all data by all users in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

i am try to build blog app using firebase database use angularfire2 , l want to allowed to users can read all data post by others users , but unsuccessfully l dont know where is problem .

database rules !

```
{
  "rules": {
  "report": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"

      }
    }    

  }
}
```

When l use this rules the users does not read all posts for other user ! , only l can read my post .

main code

```
 export class FeedPage {


itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public fire: AngularFireAuth
    ,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public toastCtrl: ToastController,public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, 
    public db: AngularFireDatabase) 
    {


      // // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
      // this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      //   map(changes => 
      //     changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      //   )

      }

      ionViewWillLoad(){
        this.fire.authState.subscribe(data => {
          if(data && data.email && data.uid){
            this.toastCtrl.create({
              message : ` welcome ${data.email}`,
              duration:2000
            }).present()


            this.itemsRef = this.db.list(`report/`+data.uid);
            // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
            this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
              map(changes => 
                changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
              )
            );


          }

        })

      }
}
```

database

```
{
  "report" : {
    "8D3sENaBcLaXoGNnh1MPuoyj5LP2" : {
      "-LWl294Hs6YjkvJE5pqi" : {
        "post" : "ali",
        "title" : "dd"
      },
      "-LWlEonKLWfOttzirqp7" : {
        "post" : "sas",
        "title" : "ass"
      },
      "-LWlGvn81Kes2A-1UcC2" : {
        "post" : "asa",
        "title" : "asass"
      }
    },
    "WUM2HBkGo8TFDeOjEqO1s3lCj1p1" : {
      "-LWlHlhyS9m3ECS3wIdk" : {
        "post" : "qwqsasasa",
        "title" : "as"
      },
      "-LWlHmXZAJdSPZurO7ii" : {
        "post" : "qwqsasasa",
        "title" : "as"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if l use this code to retrieve data l got empty html data !

```
this.itemsRef = this.db.list(`report`);
```

[image]

if l use this code to retrieve data l got only my own post not by others all users .

```
this.itemsRef = this.db.list(`report/${data.uid}`);
```

Comment: To confirm what you are having is a rule issue not code, try removing the rules you have on uid, and set both read and write to true on the root

Comment: it is same ! , l did what you talking about l get only post  by one user not all user . l want get all user post !

Comment: Then the problem is with your code not rules. and I am not good with angularFire

Comment: do you have any solution please ? l am tired form him

Comment: Your code is still getting data from the UID:    `this.itemsRef = this.db.list(`report/`+data.uid);`. Therefore the list is one folder lower, than the report listing that you are trying to get, and others suggested.

Comment: so what l should do ? @StevenScott

Comment: You would need to change the line to `this.itemsRef = this.db.list('report/');` as referenced in the other answers.

Comment: @StevenScott it is same problem

Comment: I was tired of it, tried all attempts and answers and did not solve the problem . l am don with it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allow all users to read all posts by all users, you need to grant them access to the entire `/report` node. In your security rules you do that, by move the `".read": true` rule up one level:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "report": {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

But this means you'll also need to update your code to listen to all of `/report` and then loop over the individual users under that.

Comment: it is same problem , l can red only my own post . l can read other post by other users !

Comment: Yes, I suggested to just try the read on root to confirm if it is a rules issue, but that didn't help, so my guess that it is a code issue

Answer (score 2):

As I said, I am not good with angularfire, but this line

```
this.itemsRef = this.db.list(`report/${data.uid}`);
```

To me seems to be pulling data for the user that is logging in only, 
I think it might need to be

```
this.itemsRef = this.db.list(`report`);
```

Then loop through all elements in the retrieved snapshot

**UPDATE**

Try moving the `".read": true,` above the `$uid`, just under `reports`,
copy the exact rule from the other answer

Comment: l got empty data html if l use you code .  l have to use ``report/${data.uid}`` this to get data ,but l got only one data user not looping all data

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake, re should be report, just corrected it

Comment: if l use `this.itemsRef = this.db.list(`report`);` this code l got emtpy data html !

Comment: Copy the rules from the other answer

Comment: my goodness , l dont know why l get only my post , l didnt get other post by users ! , can you access to my code using timeviewr just to check out  ?

Comment: Updated my answer